# Need to aggregate results of the query for the non-exact matching name

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a query that calculates the number of mentions of each partner in the database.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT partner, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM database.data
GROUP BY 1;
```

The output then looks like this:

```
partner  | total
---------+------
X        | 5
Y        | 3
Z        | 2
X aa     | 6
aa X     | 7
Y aa     | 1
```

What I need to do is partners like `X`, `X aa`, `aa X` to be counted together in one row (same for `Y` and `Y aa`. I tried playing with adding `HAVING` function in the end, but wasn't able to make it work and not sure it's actually the right one to use.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Does this mean that `partner` in one record must be a complete substring of another record?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly - yes. So I won't have to combine data for partners that are not substrings of another record mentioning thiat partner.

Answer (score 0):

Without optimization:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
-- rank by length
cte1 AS ( SELECT partner, total, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(partner)) rnk
          FROM  data ),
-- find pairs where partner is a substring of anoter partner
cte2 AS ( SELECT partner, total, rnk, partner short
          FROM cte1
          WHERE rnk = 1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT cte1.partner, 
                 cte1.total, 
                 cte1.rnk, 
                 CASE WHEN LOCATE(cte2.partner, cte1.partner)
                      THEN cte2.partner
                      ELSE cte1.partner
                      END
          FROM cte1, cte2
          WHERE cte1.rnk = cte2.rnk + 1 ),
-- select shortest
cte3 AS ( SELECT partner, 
                 total, 
                 rnk, short, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY partner ORDER BY LENGTH(short)) rn
          FROM cte2 )
-- get needed data
SELECT short partner, SUM(total) total
FROM cte3 
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY short
ORDER BY partner
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca5023e626872fe36db85968d391075e)

Comment: Thanks! But I get a syntax error in the first line when I try to run it and can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: @Mark Please do not tell about. Simply copy the whole error message.

Comment: What I get is: "WITH is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting EOF, BEGIN, CACHE, CHECKSUM, COMMIT.."

Comment: @Mark This is **NOT** MySQL message. It is Workbench message (?) - if so try to update it. And specify your MySQL server version - if Workbench claims that the  query is not safe for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT d1.partner, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM (SELECT * FROM database.data d1
    WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(d1.partner) = 1
    GROUP BY d1.partner
    ) d1
-- i
LEFT JOIN database.data d2 ON
        -- get x in aa x and x aa
        d2.partner LIKE CONCAT('%', d1.partner, '%')
-- remoove x aa and aa x from the count table
GROUP BY d1.partner;
```

---

With mock data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_mock_data
SELECT * FROM (
                  SELECT 'X' partner
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'Y'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'Z'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'Y aa'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'Z aa'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'X aa'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'aa Z'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'aa Y'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'aa X'
              ) A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) B;
SELECT d1.partner, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM (SELECT * FROM tmp_mock_data d1
    WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(d1.partner) = 1
    GROUP BY d1.partner
    ) d1
-- i
LEFT JOIN tmp_mock_data d2 ON
        -- get x in aa x and x aa
        d2.partner LIKE CONCAT('%', d1.partner, '%')
-- remoove x aa and aa x from the count table
GROUP BY d1.partner;
DROP TABLE tmp_mock_data;
```

Comment: Thanks! I get no results when running it though.

Comment: @Mark I've updated the answer, as it seemed buggy. Try new version.

Comment: Still don't get any results.

Comment: @Mark Well then you need to supply sample data. Because it works with the sample you've given in the 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: Do not forget to check the solution of triple data (A is substring of B which is substring of C).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT partner,COUNT(*) AS Total

FROM(

SELECT (CASE WHEN ASCII(LEFT(partner,1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 THEN  LEFT(partner,1) ELSE RIGHT(partner,1) END)  AS partner

FROM database.data)

GROUP BY 1;
```